# Error Free(): invalid size aborted core dumped

Tags: c++, stack, free

I have the following code for constructing a new object of a class. Upon compiling the compiler tells me Free(): Invalid size Aborted core(dumped)

```
                  Mountain* Chain::copie()const{
            return (new Chain(*this));
            }

          Chain::Chain(Chain const & other){
              for(auto &element: other.ChainofChain){
                  ChainofChain.push_back(element->copie());
              }
          }

          void Chain::dessine_sur(SupportADessin  & support) const {
               for(auto &element: ChainofChain){
                 element->dessine_sur(support);// 
            }
          }

          std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Mountain >> Chain::get_Chains() const
          {
            return ChainofChain;
          }


          double Chain::altitude(double x, double y) const {
            double alt = 0;

            for(auto &element : ChainofChain)
            {
              if(element->altitude(x,y) > alt){ alt = element->altitude(x,y); 
         }
            }
            return alt;
          }

        bool Chain::is_Chain()const {return true;}

        void Chain::ajoute_Mountain(Mountain*  mountain)
        {
          ChainofChain.push_back (mountain);
        }
```

where a class Chain subclass of Mountain contains a vector of pointers to objects of type Mountain(either Montagne or Chain).

Can you help me out

Comment: The code shown looks fine as is, but it is not enough to diagnose the problem. Please provide a [mcve]. Also, a vector of raw pointers is undesirable in this situation, you should consider using a vector of smart pointers instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau you ve memtioned smart pointers. I coukd use unique pointers, or what else you propose?

Comment: yes, `unique_ptr` would work, that is one of the standard smart pointer classes